# C# unable to get value from lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

Our company has purchased an app written in .NET and I have got a privilege to support it.  I have never worked with .NET therefore I need some guidance with how to use lambda.

In my cshtml file I am trying to get a value and validate if it's **NULL** or not.

I have tried to do this like so

```
var appointment = x => x.AppointmentDate;
```

I receive compiler error "**Cannot assign lambda expression to implicitly-typed local variable**". I googled the error and tried the following.

```
Func<DateTime, DateTime> appointment = x => x.AppointmentDate;
```

However now compiler gives this error "**'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'AppointmentDate' and no extension method 'AppointmentDate' accepting a first argument of type 'System.DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**
"

How can I get a value to validate from lambda?

Comment: what do you expect what `x` is?

Comment: the argument passed in is `DateTime`, it obviously **doesn't** have any the so-called property `AppointmentDate`.

Comment: Your question is a fair one.  But learning C# can be "non-trival" (not as bad as C++, though ;)).  This link might be useful intro to C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228358%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.  Also: http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda.  IMHO...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're confused by what [`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) is meant to be. The first parameter (`T`) is the *input* to the delegate; `TResult` is the output. So you probably want:

```
Func<Appointment, DateTime> appointmentFunction = x => x.AppointmentDate;
```

... where `Appointment` is the type of the object you're working with.

Of course, that won't check whether the value is `null` - and in fact if the `AppointmentDate` property is just `DateTime` then it *can't* be null, as `DateTime` is a non-nullable value type.

Note that in many cases you don't need to assign a lambda expression to a local variable - if you're calling a generic method, you can often let type inference work out the types for you. For example, if you have a `List<Appointment>` you could use:

```
var sorted = appointments.OrderBy(x => x.AppointmentDate);
```

and type inference would work out the delegate type you're interested in.

I would suggest that it's worth learning C# methodically though, rather than trying to learn it just through changes to an existing app. You could easily get into bad habits - and misunderstand fundamental language concepts - if you're not careful.

Comment: How would I validate that appointment function is not empty? `if (appointmentFunction!=null) { do something }`? How would I get a value now out of this function?

Comment: @svager: You'd call the delegate - but then it's fairly pointless using a lambda expression to start with. Why do you feel you *need* to use a lambda expression? You haven't really given us enough context for us to help you.

Comment: Vendor used lambda expressions to bound to old Telerik controls i.e column binds. I am trying to make a small change with the least amount of code. Not working out too good.

Comment: @svager: Hmm. Without any experience in the Telerik controls in question - and no hint before now that this was even what you're working with - it's not easy to help you. I go back to the point at the end of my answer: trying to learn a language just by editing an existing app isn't a great idea, IMO.

Comment: Totally agree, however this is one of those "one off" apps that are completely outside of our normal scope.

Comment: @svager: It sounds like you should try to find someone in the company who wouldn't need to invest as much time in learning the technology in order to fix the one problem then. It may even be more cost-efficient to hire a contractor for a day than to learn enough to be confident in what you're doing. C# is a generally friendly language, but by now it's quite large as well, and there can be some significant consequences in what seem like small decisions.